# One-to-one relationship in EF Core WebAPI?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working with EF Core in a .NET WebAPI project.

I'm trying to define a 1:1 relationship in my model and seed some data into it.
I get the data to seed and can see it in the DB, but the controller is not returning the related item, what am I doing wrong?

Tenant, Config Class:

```
public class Tenant
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set;}

    //Navigation Property
    public virtual Config Config { get; set; }

}

public class Config
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Tenant")]
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public int clientroute { get; set; }

    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

}
```

:DbContext Class:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>()
            .HasOne<Config>(s => s.Config)
            .WithOne(ad => ad.Tenant);
    }

    public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Config> Config { get; set; } = null!;
```

DbSeed Class:

```
dbContext.Tenants.Add(new Tenant
            {
                Name = "Tenant1",
                Config = new Config {  clientroute = 1}
            });
```

TenantsController:

```
// GET: api/Tenants
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Tenant>>> GetTenants()
    {
      if (_context.Tenants == null)
      {
          return NotFound();
      }
        return await _context.Tenants.ToListAsync();
    }
```

The relationship appears to be correct as the seed data correctly loads in the DB.
When I hit the swagger endpoint, config is null. Why?

Additionally, do i need the configuration in OnModelCreating if the Config class is decorated as such?

Answer (score 0):

This line should be changed

`return await _context.Tenants.ToListAsync();`

As

`return await _context.Tenants.Include(t => t.Config).ToListAsync();`

And this should fix the problem.

What happens here, is that `.Include()` indicates for EF to actually join the Tenants DbSet with Config DbSet and grab the data. In this case, EF is using left join so you'll get no error if the related config object does not exist in the Config DbSet.

[Docs](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx)

Comment: Yes, because lazy loading is not enabled by default in EF Core.